# How to change file contents in PHP?

Tags: php, file

I save in a file some info about users (like number of times user passed the login page, last visited time, and so on).

I want to read this info from the file, and update it (add 1 to the counter, and change the last visited time).

My question is: can I do it without opening the file twice ?

I open the first time to read the contents, and then open it again to overwrite the contents with the updated ones.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do this only opening the file once as follows:

- open the file (i.e., fopen('data.txt','w+') )
- read the data (fread)
- write the data (fwrite)
- close the file (fclose)

Comment: But after I read the contents the position of the file pointer will be at the end of the file, so why fwrite will write the contents at the beginning of the file ?

Comment: Then take a look at rewind() as well